# Inheritance of POST variables collected via CORS

Tags: php, ajax, variables, include, cors

In `get.php` I have variables collects from a post. see bellow.

**get.php**

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
```

These are posted from a different website via Ajax and CORS

**different website**

```
  $("#abi_test").click(function (event) {
            $.post(
                "http://website.com/get.php",
                {
                    name: "Tom",
                    age: "30",
                    email: "johnsmith@gmail.com",
                },
                function (data) {
                    $('#stage').html(data);
                }
            );
```

I now need to use these variables posted to `get.php` in a different page on the same website as `get.php`

This Is what I have tried

**Pageb.php**

```
 <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<?php

include 'get.php';

echo "your email $email"; // A green apple
?>
```

Comment: In you get.php file either post or get Pageb.php with the parameters you need.

Comment: that is what im trying

Answer (score 0):

You must change you request from `http://website.com/get.php` to `"http://website.com/Pageb.php`.

Every thing should work fine.

Comment: I need the variables on both pages

Comment: But by including get.php within you Pageb.php, your get.php script will also be executed.
Did you try?

Comment: yes, all the script from get.phi is there but not the variables

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear. When you do `include 'get.php';` in your Pageb.php, all the code in get.php will be executed, AND the variables will be accessible to Pageb.php. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes i have, i dont need the contents printed i just need access to the variables

Comment: But you will have access to do whatever you want. Including print them. What went wrong?

Comment: Im thinking because the post variables are via CORs i need to turn them into global variables

Comment: CORs or not, the php variable scope doesn't change. It there any error being shown?

Comment: No errors, just can see them. im going to de bug this morning